# Why I'm not able to select cell in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I created my UICollectionView programmatically, set delegate, dataSource. I'm able to scroll my UICollectionView, click buttons inside of cells, but I'm not able to select my cell. DidSelect function does not fire at all!

My code:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - 15, height: 360)
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = -12

    // MARK: - Suggested Posts CollectionView
    self.suggestedPostsCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height - 360, width: CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height: 360), collectionViewLayout: layout)



    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SuggestedPostsCell", bundle: nil)
    suggestedPostsCollectionView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "suggestedPostsCell")

    suggestedPostsCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    suggestedPostsCollectionView.delegate = self
    suggestedPostsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    suggestedPostsCollectionView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    self.scrollView.addSubview(suggestedPostsCollectionView)
```

I'm working over this problem over 2 weeks and I do not understand why it happens. Can anyone help me?

Comment: try to with  `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false`

Comment: @NazmulHasan nothing again =/

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another view (transparent) on top of the collection view? If there is, a press would hit that view and not make it to the collection view

Comment: @Shades I can scroll my collection view and press buttons inside of a cell. So, I do not think so

Answer (score 0):

Try in the `prepareForSegue`'s function:

```
     let cellList = [YourObject]()

     let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(YourCell() as UICollectionViewCell)
     let singleCell = cellList[indexPath!.row]

//example retrieving data from cell
singleCell.name = user_name
```